# How to randomize nodes of a binary tree without using additional data structures?

Tags: tree, nodes

The question says it all.

How can we randomize nodes of a binary tree without using additional data structures?

"Without additional data structures" means Stack, Array, or any other data structure cannot be used.

Comment: The question title (as of this writing) says "randomize", but in a comment you say that each node must move. These are two different concepts. An unbiased random permutation can randomly leave certain elements in a fixed position. A derangement is a permutation that leaves no element fixed. Do you want a random permutation or a random derangement?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).  It only requires N steps where N is the number of nodes in your binary tree.
The algorithm will need the following modifications:

1. When you generate an index, you'll need to map that index to a node in the binary tree.  How you index the nodes is up to you as long as the indexing is consistent.  For example, you could index your binary tree like so:

(Please excuse the ASCII art)

```
   0  
  / \
 1   2
/ \ / \
3 4 5 6
```

2. When you exchange two nodes, make sure you only swap the nodes' *values*.  Exchanging their children will cause issues (consider what would occur if you swapped the children of the root node with any other node).

The algorithm would look something like the following:

```
for ( i = num_nodes - 1; i > 0; i-- ) {
    // 0 <= j <= i
    j = random_index(0, i);

    i_value = get_node_value(i);
    j_value = get_node_value(j);

    // Swap the two nodes' values
    set_node_value(j, i_value);
    set_node_value(i, j_value);
}
```

Comment: Sounds interesting, but does the algorithm assure that each node has equal probability of getting values from any other node? That was one of the requirement of the solution. So this means for every node j E [0, i], the random index must exclude j. Hence it must be from [0,j-1] and [j+1, i]?

Comment: Yes, the algorithm's output is unbaised so that every possible output permutation is just as likely.  I'm not sure I fully understand your second question, but the reason `j` is selected as `0 <= j <= i` is so that there's a possibility that `j = i` which means the node's value will remain unchanged.  I would recommend reading the Fisher-Yates article section on [potential sources of bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Potential_sources_of_bias) which may explain it better.